# Scikit-learn cross val score: too many indices for array

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have the following code

```
 from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
 from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
 #split the dataset for train and test
 combnum['is_train'] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, len(combnum)) <= .75
 train, test = combnum[combnum['is_train']==True], combnum[combnum['is_train']==False]

 et = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=200, max_depth=None, min_samples_split=10, random_state=0)
 min_samples_split=10, random_state=0  )

 labels = train[list(label_columns)].values
 tlabels = test[list(label_columns)].values

 features = train[list(columns)].values
 tfeatures = test[list(columns)].values

 et_score = cross_val_score(et, features, labels, n_jobs=-1)
 print("{0} -> ET: {1})".format(label_columns, et_score))
```

Checking the shape of the arrays:

```
 features.shape
 Out[19]:(43069, 34)
```

And

```
labels.shape
Out[20]:(43069, 1)
```

and I'm getting:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

and this relevant part of the traceback:

```
---> 22 et_score = cross_val_score(et, features, labels, n_jobs=-1)
```

I'm creating the data from Pandas dataframes and I searched here and saw some reference to possible errors via this method but can't figure out how to correct?
What the data arrays look like:
features

```
Out[21]:
array([[ 0.,  1.,  1., ...,  0.,  0.,  1.],
   [ 0.,  1.,  1., ...,  0.,  0.,  1.],
   [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  0.,  0.,  1.],
   ..., 
   [ 0.,  0.,  1., ...,  0.,  0.,  1.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  1., ...,  0.,  0.,  1.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  1., ...,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

labels

```
Out[22]:
array([[1],
   [1],
   [1],
   ..., 
   [1],
   [1],
   [1]])
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback. Which version of scikit-learn are you on? And can you try to pass ``labels.ravel()`` instead?

Comment: labels.ravel() did it! Was just reading another error , that suggest that using different code,, I'm on Scikit learn 17 dev0

Comment: @AndreasMueller Thank you so much for the quick response! Might help a few others if you can make an answer..

Comment: I don't think this is a good error. Can you please open an issue in the issue tracker?

Comment: MMM where should I post the error to? Pandas or scikit-learn?

Comment: Scikit-learn. with a minimum reproducing example that doesn't rely on pandas with generated numpy arrays.

Comment: Given that a pandas dataframe doesn't have a `ravel` method, is `numpy.squeeze`-ing whatever you want y values to be a more robust solution? (@AndreasMueller)

Comment: @James What happens to a dataframe if you squeeze it? Is ``DataFrame.values`` not always 2d?

Comment: @AndreasMueller values of a DataFrame with one column are n x 1 (so yes). `np.squeeze` will shrink to shape `(n,)` if the dataframe shape is n x 1 and won't modify shape otherwise (which will throw this error). `np.ravel` will flatten any numpy array, so if your shape is wrong to begin with, you'll end up with something really long that also can't be aligned I think?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

When we do cross validation in scikit-learn, the process requires an `(R,)` shape label instead of `(R,1)`. Although they are the same thing to some extend, their indexing mechanisms are different. So in your case, just add:

```
c, r = labels.shape
labels = labels.reshape(c,)
```

before passing it to the cross-validation function.

Answer (score 15):

It seems to be fixable if you specify the target labels as a single data column from Pandas.  If the target has multiple columns, I get a similar error.  For example try:

```
labels = train['Y']
```

Comment: This answer was more simple and direct. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `.ravel()` to the Y/Labels variable passed into the formula helped solve this problem within KNN as well.

Answer (score 0):

try target:

```
y=df['Survived']
```

instead , i used

```
y=df[['Survived']]
```

which made the target y a dateframe, it seems series would be ok

Answer (score 0):

You might need to play with the dimensions a bit, e.g.

```
et_score = cross_val_score(et, features, labels, n_jobs=-1)[:,n]
```

or

```
 et_score = cross_val_score(et, features, labels, n_jobs=-1)[n,:]
```

n being the dimension.