# GridSearchCV error "Too many indices in the array"

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, grid-search

I am using a supervised learning algorithm Random Forest classifier for training the data.

```
    clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50, n_jobs=3, random_state=42)
```

Different parameter in the grid are:

```
    param_grid = { 
    'n_estimators': [200, 700],
    'max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2'],
    'max_depth': [5,10],
    'min_samples_split': [5,10]
    }
```

Classifier "clf" and parameter grid "param_grid" are passed in the GridSearhCV method.

```
    clf_rfc = GridSearchCV(estimator=clf, param_grid=param_grid)
```

When I fit the features with labels using

```
    clf_rfc.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I get the error "Too many indices in the array". Shape of X_train is (204,3) and of y_train is (204,1).

Tried with the option   clf_rfc.fit(X_train.values, y_train.values) but could not get rid of the error.

Any suggestions would be appreciated !!

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of error.

Comment: Also try reshaping your `y_train` to y_train.reshape(204) to make it a sequence from a 1-d array

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in previous post the problems appears to be in y_train which dimensions are (204,1). I think this is the problem instead of (204,1) should be (204,), click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39106877/7127519) for more info.

So if you rewrite y_train everything should be fine:

```
c, r = y_train.shape
y_train = y_train.reshape(c,)
```

If it gives as error such as: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'reshape' then try:

```
c, r = y_train.shape
y_train = y_train.values.reshape(c,)
```

Answer (score 1):

The shape of the 'y-train' dataframe is not correct.
Try this:

`clf_rfc.fit(X_train, y_train[0].values)`

OR

`clf_rfc.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())`

Answer (score 1):

`y_train` should be a 1-dimensional array

I have tried `clf_rfc.fit(X_train, y_train.flatten())`, and it did work!